# JPA derived composite key

Tags: jpa, jdbc, orm, eclipselink, dao

I'm learning JPA 2.1. I have designed a database using sql but unable to do the same using JPA 2.1. I'm listing out the sql script.

```
create table SchoolClass (classNo int, constraint schoolClassPK Primary Key (classNo));
create table Section (classNo int, sectionId varchar(4), constraint sectionPK Primary Key(classNo, sectionId), constraint sectionClassNoFK Foreign Key (classNo) References SchoolClass(classNo));
create table Student (classNo int, sectionId varchar(4), rollNo int, name varchar(30), constraint studentPK Primary Key (classNo, sectionId, rollNo), constraint studentClassNoFK Foreign Key (classNo, sectionId) References Section(classNo, sectionId));
```

My problem is in implementing Student class. Here is what I have attempted to do with JPA:

```
@Entity
public class Schoolclass implements Serializable {

@Id
private int classNo;

//other members follow
}



// IdClass
public class SectionCK implements Serializable {

private int classNo;
private String sectionId;

// hashCode(), equals(Object), other members follow
}



@Entity
@IdClass(SectionCK.class)
public class Section implements Serializable {

@Id
private int sectionPK;

@Id
private String sectionId;

@Id
@ManyToOne(cascade = { PERSIST, MERGE })
@JoinColumn(name="SchoolClass_ClassNo", referencedColumnName="classNo")
private SchoolClass classNo;

//other members follow
}



// IdClass
public class StudentCK implements Serializable {

private int classNo;
private String sectionId;
private int rollNo;

// hashCode(), equals(Object), other members follow
}



@Entity
@IdClass(StudentCK.class)
public class Student implements Serializable {

@Id
private int rollNo;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@Id
@ManyToOne(cascade = { PERSIST, MERGE })
@JoinColumns({
@JoinColumn(name="Section_SectionId", referencedColumnName="sectionId"),
@JoinColumn(name="Section_ClassNo", referencedColumnName="classNo")
})
private Section sectionId;

//other members follow
}
```

But this fails to produce the above database. What changes are needed?

Comment: Am I missing something in your SQL code? With table `Section` you don't define `classSection` column but referencing it in PK. Same with table `Student`: `classSection` where? in `Student` you are referencing `classNo` from `Section` as an FK. Such column does only exist in `SchoolClass`.

Comment: `classNo` is Ok. Only `classSection` uphold

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is failing?  zbigniewTomczak's answer seems correct, so if it isn't working, show what error or what it produces.  You join columns in the above example seem wrong, as there isn't a "SchoolClass_ClassNo" field in the Section table - it should be "classNo" if that is the foreign key field used.  You have the same issues with the joincolumns defined in the Student mapping - they dont match the fields you want in the student table.

Comment: @zbigniewTomczak

Thank you for pointing out the problem with the SQL script and I have rectified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways try starting from following code and work your way towards desired mapping. Remember that names, types and count of the fields in `@IdClass` must match those marked `@Id` in entity.

```
public class SectionCK {
    private String sectionId;
    private int schoolClass;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(SectionCK.class)
public class Section implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String sectionId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="classNo")
    private SchoolClass schoolClass;
}

public class StudentCK implements Serializable {
    private int rollNo;
    private SectionCK section;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(StudentCK.class)
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private int rollNo;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="sectionId", referencedColumnName="sectionId"),
    @JoinColumn(name="classNo", referencedColumnName="classNo")
    })
    private Section section;

}
```

This code generate following tables:

```
Table: Student
COLUMN_NAME         |TYPE_NAME
------------------------------
ROLLNO              |INTEGER  
NAME                |VARCHAR  
CLASSNO             |INTEGER 
SECTIONID           |VARCHAR  

Table: SchoolClass
COLUMN_NAME         |TYPE_NAME
------------------------------
CLASSNO             |INTEGER 

Table: Section
COLUMN_NAME         |TYPE_NAME
------------------------------
SECTIONID           |VARCHAR  
CLASSNO             |INTEGER
```

Comment: Also there is no difference between my code and your code. This is what I have already tried but does not work.

Comment: Yes, there are differences. 1. Note that I'm using `SectionCK` in `StudentCK`. 2. You would have `@JoinColumn` `name` attribute produce incorrect column names. Mine are OK. 3. You also mixing names between `@Id` name and `@IdClass` field name (`sectionPK`).

Comment: zbigniewTomczak Thank you for pointing out the problem and giving the solution.